# React Router - different links on different pages

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a navigation with the React.Router paths as following:

- example 1: leads to "/example1"
- example 2: leads to "/example2"
- example 3: leads to "/example3"

if I click example 3 from the start page (/), I want to route to "/example3".
if I click example 3 from the example2 page (/example2), I want to route to "/?id=x"

How can I achieve this? It only renders once in my case and then stuck with it.

Thank you in advance,
J. Doe

Comment: `if I click example 3 from the example2 page` have you written any code for this? If yes, please provide same

Comment: yes, here:
  <Switch>
            <Route path={"example1"} component={example1}/>

            {window.location.href.includes("/info/") ? (
                <Route path={"?id=x"} component={example3}/>
                ):(<Route path={"example3"} component={example3}/>)}
           
            <Route exact path={"/"} component={startpage}/>
        </Switch>

Answer (score 0):

It would be much better if you could provide us with a sample of your code. But, generally, to handle something like this, our code would be something as below:

```
import React from 'react'
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'

export default function App() {
  const history = useHistory()

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick = {() => history.push('/example1')}>go to example 1</button>
      <button onClick = {() => history.push('/example2')}>go to example 2</button>
      <button onClick = {() => history.push('/example3')}>go to example 3</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and you need to define your routings in your routing component as bewlo:

```
    import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
    
    export default function Routings() {
       <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/example1" component={Example1} />
                <Route path="/example2" component={Example2} />
                <Route path="/example3" component={Example3} />
            </Switch>
        </Router>
}
```